# Pop up alert on waffle ?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, popup

Hello Is it is possible to add a pop up message for people that click on the waffle on SharePoint Online?
[image]

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What is the business reason?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add custom tile to app launcher, but no js code can be added to it OOB, so in my opinion there are two solutions which varies in scope and complexity:

1. Add Content Editor Web Part with custom javascript which will add event listener to App Launcher icon. This will work on a single page or on all pages which use your custom Page Layout with mentioned code
2. Use custom master page with embedded js code which will do what you ask for. Using master page you can achieve desired effect across whole site, but it seems to be a 'big gun' if you only want to add such a simple feature.

It is not possible to add Custom Action with js code which would do what you asked for (in on premise it would be possible, but not in Online)